# Inputting Customer.customerID into Advert.cutomerID using LinQ to Sql in MVC3 Razor

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-3

Been at this far too long; trying to populate a field in a record with a foreign key, it is dependent on which user is logged on.

Shown below is a view bag which displayed the Firstname of the customer in a dropdown, which the user had to select. It would then put the CustomerID into the record when it was created. This method was impractical

```
ViewBag.CustomerID = new SelectList(db.Customers, "CustomerID", "FName");
```

Below is an attempt to input the foreign key automatically by finding the CustomerID and then inputting the custoemrID into a hidden field on a form.

```
   public ActionResult Create()
    {
        var CusID = from c in db.Customers
            where c.UserName == "User.Identity.Name"
            select c.CustomerID;
    return View(new CarAdvert { UserName = @User.Identity.Name, CustomerID = CusID });
    }
```

The error: Cannot implicitly convert type system.linq.Iqueryable <-int-> to int

The approach taken (is this correct! - Any advice on the subject welcome)

any more info need please ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the error:

```
var CusID = (from c in db.Customers
        where c.UserName == User.Identity.Name
        select c.CustomerID).Single();
```

Instead of .Single you can/should use .First, .FirstOrDefault, ... depending on your requirements.

Comment: "User.Identity.Name" shouldn't be in quotes - it's not a string literal, it's a property.